# I am using Firebase authentication for my application. There seems to be an infinite loop where the page keeps being redirected over and over again

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

The following function is to redirect the user to "Select Stream.html" when the user logs in.It keeps on replacing the location over and over again.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        window.location.replace("Select Stream.html");
      // User is signed in.
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
      window.location.replace("index.html");
    }
  });
```

I am new to coding.

```js
Here is the Log in Function

function login()
{
    var userEmail=document.getElementById("email-field").value;
    var userPassword=document.getElementById("password-field").value;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        
      /*  window.location='Select Stream.html'; */
        window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);
        // ...
      });
}


The Login function will be triggered when the signin-button is clicked.
```

```html
<input onclick="login()" type="submit" name="signin-button" value="Sign In"/>
```

Comment: Are you calling `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` inside any function or is it just added you've shown? If it is not inside any fucntion, you need to call it inside a function and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change the name of `Select Stream.html` to have no spaces or capital letters. This is common practice, and I recommend changing the name of the file to `select_stream.html`.

Before opening `select_stream.html` or `index.html`, check whether the user is already on that page to prevent the page from refreshing, like this:

```
if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("select_stream.html") == -1){
    window.location.replace("select_stream.html");
  }
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("index.html") == -1){
    window.location.replace("index.html");
  }
}
```

The `window.location.href` variable refers to the URL of the current page, and the `.indexOf` function allows you to check if a value is contained inside the URL. The `.indexOf` function returns `-1` if the specified value could not be found within the string, so this code simply only redirects if the user is not already on the redirect page.

Comment: You are a lifesaver man! This worked like a charm :) Thanks for explaining the code as well